# Importing CSV in GAS - too slow

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that imports a CSV file.
It works, but it's really slow in my opinion.
Since the CSV file is pretty big the script exceeds the maximum execution time.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to increase the speed of my code?

FYI: Due to the S3 authentication I cannot use a built-in Sheets function.

```
function myFunction() {

  var liquidityBalance = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(liquidityBalanceSheet).getSheetByName('Liquidity');
  var s3 = S3.getInstance(awsAccessKeyId, awsSecretKey);

  var fromS3 = s3.getObject(bucket, file);
  var data = Utilities.parseCsv(fromS3.getDataAsString(), '\t');
  var csv = []
  liquidityBalance.clearContents();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = []
    for (var a = 0; a < data[i].length; a++) {
      row.push(data[i][a]);
    }
    liquidityBalance.appendRow(row);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully the following code will run faster.  This code assembles all the data and then writes the assembled data in one action instead of appending rows one at a time.  If the code still times out, then you will need to run partial amounts of data and know where you left off last to continue the next batch.

```
function myFunction() {
  var a,csv,data,fromS3,i,L,L2,lastRow,liquidityBalance,
      outerArray,row,s3,thisRow;

  liquidityBalance = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(liquidityBalanceSheet).getSheetByName('Liquidity');
  s3 = S3.getInstance(awsAccessKeyId, awsSecretKey);

  fromS3 = s3.getObject(bucket, file);
  data = Utilities.parseCsv(fromS3.getDataAsString(), '\t');
  csv = [];

  lastRow = liquidityBalance.getLastRow();

  liquidityBalance.clearContents();

  outerArray = [];

  L = data.length;
  L2 = data[0].length;//Number of elements in an inner array

  for (i = 0; i < L; i++) {
    row = [];//reset on every loop
    thisRow = data[i];

    for (a = 0; a < L2; a++) {
      row.push(thisRow[a]);
    }

    outerArray.push(thisRow);
  }

  liquidityBalance.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, outerArray.length, L2).setValues(outerArray);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sandy. I've made some minor alterations to your code (lastRow variable is not necessary, needs to be a clean sheet import every time; pushing row to outerArray; moved setValues out the for loop). The script runs in a few seconds now!

Comment: Thanks for the vote and letting me know the results.  I updated the answer with that critical change of moving `setValues()` out of the loop.

Comment: There is one more improvement. You don't need to create a new 2D array, the parseCsv function already returns a 2D array so you can pass its results  (the data variable) directly to setValues - you can easily eliminate those 13 lines dedicated to multiple for loops.